# The convergence of $f_n(t)$ to $f_n$ in the supremum norm implies $f_n(t)\rightarrow f(t)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm awful at these problems so I was just posting this to confirm whether my solution is correct.

As:
$$(f_n)_{n\geq 1} \in X \rightarrow f \in X \mbox{ in the supremum norm}$$
$$\mbox{For all } \epsilon >0 \mbox{ there exists } N_\epsilon \mbox{ such that } \|f_n-f_m\|<\epsilon \mbox{ for all } N_\epsilon<n,m$$
Let $m\rightarrow\infty$ and fix $t_0$ then:
$$|f_n(t_0) - f(t_0)|\leq \|f_n-f\|<\epsilon$$
Hence since $t_0$ was picked arbitrarily we see that $f_n\rightarrow f$ for all $t$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.